# Using session to store post username and display in HomePage after verifying

Tags: php, session, post, authentication

there are three files that i use to create a login function. I wish to grab the username from checkLogin.php to display on homepage.php. Please Help Me !! Thank You !

```
Error message : Notice: Undefined variable: _session
```

**Login file**

```
Username:
input name="username" type="text" size="30"  maxlength="100"
Password:
input name="password" type="password" size="30"
Types of User
input type="radio" name="usertype" value="1"Customer
input type="radio" name="usertype" value="2"Modeller
input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Login" class="imgBtn"/>
```

Second file is **checkLogin.php**

```
<?php session_start();
```

Third file is **homepage.php** (at the top of which I started the session)

```
echo "Username : ".$_session['username']
```

Comment: checkLogin.php i use $_session['username']=$_POST['username']; to store

Comment: You should first show the code that you got, then we can help you.

Comment: thank you guys ! i already solve ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names in PHP are case-sensitive thus, the correct usage would be

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

See how session is capitalized?

Answer (score 2):

After calling `session_start()`, you need to assign posted 'username' to session variable, like below:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Also wrong usage of global variable name, `$_SESSION` in your script

```
echo "Username : ".$_session['username'];
```

It should be

```
echo "Username : ".$_SESSION['username'];
```